# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}} dx$

Tags: integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

It's an exercise I took from an exam of Measure Theory.

Using all the theorems it needs, evaluate:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}} dx $$

It has an additional hint: from $n>2$ look at the integral like $$ \int_0^{+\infty} = \int_0^1 + \int_1^{n^2-n} + \int_{n^2-n}^{n^2+n}+\int_{n^2+n}^{+\infty}$$

Moreover the function has no elementary primitive, but it is the product of two functions that do have elementary primitive. This can be helpful after having done the right considerations.

Comment: I suppose you mean "calculate" or "find". You cannot "solve" a limit, limit is not a problem or question.

Comment: yes, i'm not english mother-tongue so excuse me for the mistake

Comment: Not mine either :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the given hint we have that for $n\geq 2$,

i) if $x\in [0,1]$ then
$$\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2-1}},$$
ii) if $x\in [1,n^2-n]$ then
$$\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}}\leq \frac{e^{-n^2}}{\sqrt{n}},$$
if $x\in [n^2+n,+\infty)$ then
$$\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}}\leq \frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
By using these estimates, you may show that the three related integrals go to zero. It remains to consider the integral:
$$\int_{n^2-n}^{n^2+n}\frac{e^{-n^2x}}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}} \,dx\leq e^{-n^2(n^2-n)}\int_{n^2-n}^{n^2+n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{|x-n^2|}}=e^{-n^2(n^2-n)}2\int_{0}^{n}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: for the last integral can't i say that it's less than $\frac{e^{-n^4+n^2}}{\sqrt{n}}(2n)$ ?

Comment: Yes! Note that in $[n^2-n,n^2+n]$ the denominator $\sqrt{|x-n^2|}$ goes to zero.